# How can I switch to another view (passing through prepareForSegue two values) from uitableviewcell by clicking a button in the center of the cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

I've a tableView and I'd like to switch to another view by clicking a button in the center of the cell. I use dynamic cells.

So, I want to switch to a view (in a navigation controller) with the click of a button in a cell, how can I do it in prepareForSegue? I can get the index of the cell, and then to do this step by clicking the disclosure, but when I click on my button located in the center of the cell, the indexpath does not exist. Here the code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *destination = segue.destinationViewController;
    if ([destination respondsToSelector:@selector(setDelegate:)]) {
        [destination setValue:self forKey:@"delegate"];
    }
    if ([destination respondsToSelector:@selector(setSelection:)]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableFeed indexPathForCell:sender];
        NSString *idUser = [self.arrIDUser objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"%@",idUser);
        NSString *pattern = [self.arrPattern objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSMutableDictionary *selection = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:idUser,@"idUser", pattern, @"pattern", nil];
        [destination setValue:selection forKey:@"selection"];
    }
}
```

Comment: What triggers the segue? button in the cell or disclosure indicator

Comment: check my answer for the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to grab the cell, then its superview i.e UITableViewCellContentView, then the table that has this cell. Here is the code.

```
    -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"prepare for segue");   
    //sender is UIRoundRectButton
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) [[sender superview] superview];
    UITableView *table = (UITableView*)[[[sender superview] superview] superview];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [table indexPathForCell:cell];

    NSLog(@"%i %i",indexPath.section,indexPath.row);  

}
```

This would give you the index path for the cell in which the button was tapped.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the indexPath by going to the superview of the button to get the content view and then to the superview of the content view to get the cell. But this is kind of ugly.

A better approach can be found in [iOS Recipes](http://www.amazon.de/iOS-Recipes-Awesome-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356743/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1375352758&sr=8-1&keywords=ios%20recipes) where they transform the origin of the button to the table view via [convertPoint:toView:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/convertPoint%3atoView%3a) and then call [indexPathForRowAtPoint:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/indexPathForRowAtPoint%3a) to get the indexPath.

Answer (score 0):

```
 you have to create button in cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method and assign tag to taht button. Based on that you will get that which row has selected.   

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     selectedDealIndex = indexPath.row;  //here you will get selected index 
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"your_seguename" sender:self]; //here you have to pass your seguename which you have written in xib[in properywindow]
}
```